# Where does MediaMonkey store the paths you've selected to monitor?

Tags: windows-10, mediamonkey

I use MediaMonkey to manage my music files. I also have another program that goes off and finds missing lyrics for songs. This second program works well, but unfortunately MediaMonkey doesn't recognise that the tracks have lyrics until I rescan the files.

I could select the root of my music folders and scan the whole structure on startup, but with each album I add that process gets longer and longer and I'm scanning thousands of files that haven't changed.

An ideal solution would be for the lyric finder to update the folders to be scanned on startup so that MediaMonkey only rescans those files that have been updated. I can then clear the selection the next time I open MediaMonkey. These folders are persisted but I can't find out where the list is stored. I've checked the registry and the folders under Program Files, Program Data and Users\<user>\App Data and drawn a blank.

Where does MediaMonkey store this list of folders to scan?

[image: Screen shot of MediaMonkey's File Monitor dialog]

Answer (score 0):

The folders are stored in the `MediaMonkey.ini` file in

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\MediaMonkey
```

In the section called `[AutoScan]` it adds a set of entries for each folder being scanned. For example, I've set it to monitor two folders:

```
FolderCount=2
Path1=E:\Chris\music\Annie Lennox\
Subfolders1=1
ScanOnStart1=1
ConstantMonitoring1=0
Path2=E:\Chris\music\Lorde\
Subfolders2=1
ScanOnStart2=1
ConstantMonitoring2=0
```

To update this I'd need to increment the `FolderCount` and add four new entries for the new path being monitored.